# fill line graph area with a color android

Tags: android, graph

I have created a line graph using GraphView demo.But i need to fill the areas between the points with a specific color.

[image: Line graph with color]

This is what i want to achieve.Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version, the background color of the LineGraphView is hardcoded.

If you want to change the color, you have to change it in the source code. So check out the source code from Github and modify to your needs.

This is the line you need to modify:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/com/jjoe64/graphview/LineGraphView.java#L25

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need!